# LTSpice throwing "time step too small" error with third party op amp model

Tags: ltspice

This is my first post in the community, so forgive me if I'm in the wrong place or if this is a basic question. I'm trying to run an LTSpice transient simulation of the following circuit that contains a third party model for the MCP6001 op amp:
[image]

However, when I attempt to run this simulation, I'm met with the following error:

`Analysis: Time step too small; initial timepoint: trouble with node "u1:21"`

Here's the model, in case it's of any use:

```
.SUBCKT MCP6001 1 2 3 4 5
*               | | | | |
*               | | | | Output
*               | | | Negative Supply
*               | | Positive Supply
*               | Inverting Input
*               Non-inverting Input
*
********************************************************************************
* Software License Agreement                                                   *
*                                                                              *
* The software supplied herewith by Microchip Technology Incorporated (the     *
* "Company") is intended and supplied to you, the Company's customer, for use  *
* soley and exclusively on Microchip products.                                 *
*                                                                              *
* The software is owned by the Company and/or its supplier, and is protected   *
* under applicable copyright laws. All rights are reserved. Any use in         *
* violation of the foregoing restrictions may subject the user to criminal     *
* sanctions under applicable laws, as well as to civil liability for the       *
* breach of the terms and conditions of this license.                          *
*                                                                              *
* THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED IN AN "AS IS" CONDITION. NO WARRANTIES, WHETHER    *
* EXPRESS, IMPLIED OR STATUTORY, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO, IMPLIED        *
* WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE APPLY TO  *
* THIS SOFTWARE. THE COMPANY SHALL NOT, IN ANY CIRCUMSTANCES, BE LIABLE FOR    *
* SPECIAL, INCIDENTAL OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES, FOR ANY REASON WHATSOEVER.     *
********************************************************************************
*
* Macromodel for the MCP6001/2/4 op amp family:
*   MCP6001, MCP6001R, MCP6001U, MCP6002, MCP6004
*
* Revision History:
*   REV A: 21-Jun-02, Created model
*   REV B: 16-Jul-02, Improved output stage
*   REV C: 03-Jan-03, Added MCP6001
*   REV D: 19-Aug-06, Added over temperature, improved output stage, 
*                     fixed overdrive recovery time
*   REV E: 27-Jul-07, Updated output impedance for better model stability w/cap load
*   REV F: 09-Jul-12, Added MCP6001R, MCP6001U
*
* Recommendations:
*   Use PSPICE (other simulators may require translation)
*   For a quick, effective design, use a combination of: data sheet
*     specs, bench testing, and simulations with this macromodel
*   For high impedance circuits, set GMIN=100F in .OPTIONS
*
* Supported:
*   Typical performance for temperature range (-40 to 125) degrees Celsius
*   DC, AC, Transient, and Noise analyses.
*   Most specs, including: offsets, DC PSRR, DC CMRR, input impedance,
*     open loop gain, voltage ranges, supply current, ... , etc.
*   Temperature effects for Ibias, Iquiescent, Iout short circuit 
*   current, Vsat on both rails, Slew Rate vs. Temp and P.S.
*
* Not Supported:
*   Some Variation in specs vs. Power Supply Voltage
*   Monte Carlo (Vos, Ib), Process variation
*   Distortion (detailed non-linear behavior)
*   Behavior outside normal operating region
*
* Input Stage
V10  3 10 -500M
R10 10 11 6.90K 
R11 10 12 6.90K 
C11 11 12 0.2p
C12 1  0 6.00P 
E12 71 14 POLY(4) 20 0 21 0 26 0 27 0   1.00M 20.1 20.1 1 1
G12 1 0 62 0 1m 
M12 11 14 15 15 NMI L=2.00U W=42.0U
M14 12  2 15 15 NMI L=2.00U W=42.0U
G14 2 0 62 0 1m 
C14  2  0 6.00P 
I15 15  4 50.0U
V16 16  4 -300M
GD16 16 1 TABLE {V(16,1)} ((-100,-1p)(0,0)(1m,1n)(2m,1m)(3m,1)) 
V13  3 13 -300M
GD13 2 13 TABLE {V(2,13)} ((-100,-1p)(0,0)(1m,1n)(2m,1m)(3m,1)) 
R70 1 0 20.6T  
R71 2 0 20.6T 
R72 1 2 20T 
I80 1 2 0.5p
*
* Noise, PSRR, and CMRR
I20 21 20 423U
D20 20  0 DN1
D21  0 21 DN1
G26  0 26 POLY(1) 3 4   110U -49U
R26 26  0 1
G27  0 27 POLY(2) 1 0 2 0   -440U 39.7U 39.7U
R27 27  0 1
*
* Open Loop Gain, Slew Rate
G30  0 30 POLY(1) 12 11   0 1
R30 30  0 1K
G31  0 31 POLY(1) 3 4 86 5.25
R31 31  0 1 TC=2.8m
GD31 30 31 TABLE {V(30,31)} ((-11,-1)(-10,-10n)(0,0)(1m,1000))
G32 32  0 POLY(1) 3 4 113.7 3.5
R32 32  0 1 TC=2.65m
GD32 30 32 TABLE {V(30,32)} ((-1m,-1000)(0,0)(10,10n)(11,1))
G33 0 33 30 0 1m
R33 33 0 1k
G34  0 34 33 0 425M
R34  34 0 1K
C34  34 0 74U
G37  0 37 34 0 1m
R37  37 0 1K
C37  37 0 41.6P 
G38  0 38 37 0 1m
R38  39 0 1K
L38  38 39 100U
E38  35 0 38 0 1
G35 33 0 TABLE {V(35,3)} ((-1,-1n)(0,0)(16,1n))(16.1,1))
G36 33 0 TABLE {V(35,4)} ((-16.1,-1)((-16,-1n)(0,0)(1,1n))
*
* Output Stage 
R80 50 0 100MEG
G50 0 50 57 96 2
R58 57  96 0.50
R57 57  0 750
C58  5  0 2.00P
G57  0 57 POLY(3) 3 0 4 0 35 0   0 0.67M 0.67M 1.5M
GD55 55 57 TABLE {V(55,57)} ((-2m,-1)(-1m,-1m)(0,0)(10,1n))
GD56 57 56 TABLE {V(57,56)} ((-2m,-1)(-1m,-1m)(0,0)(10,1n))
E55 55  0 POLY(2) 3 0 51 0 -0.7m 1 -40.0M
E56 56  0 POLY(2) 4 0 52 0 1.2m 1 -37.0M
R51 51 0 1k
R52 52 0 1k
GD51 50 51 TABLE {V(50,51)} ((-10,-1n)(0,0)(1m,1m)(2m,1))
GD52 50 52 TABLE {V(50,52)} ((-2m,-1)(-1m,-1m)(0,0)(10,1n)) 
G53  3  0 POLY(1) 51 0  -49U 1M
G54  0  4 POLY(1) 52 0  -49U -1M
*
* Current Limit 
G99 96 5 99 0 1 
R98 0 98 1 TC=-2.8M,2.63U 
G97 0 98 TABLE { V(96,5) } ((-11.0,-10.0M)(-1.00M,-9.9M)(0,0)(1.00M,9.9M)(11.0,10.0M)) 
E97 99 0 VALUE { V(98)*((V(3)-V(4))*359M + 310M)} 
D98 4 5 DESD 
D99 5 3 DESD 
*
* Temperature / Voltage Sensitive IQuiscent
R61 0 61 100 TC 3.11M 4.51U
G61 3 4 61 0 1
G60 0 61 TABLE {V(3, 4)} 
+ ((0,0)(900M,0.0106U)(1.00,0.20U)(1.3,0.63U)
+ (1.5,0.66U)(1.6,1.06U)(5.5,1.10U))
*
* Temp Sensitive offset voltage 
I73 0 70 DC 1uA 
R74 0 70 1 TC=2 
E75 1 71 70 0 1 
*
* Temp Sensistive IBias 
I62 0 62 DC 1uA 
R62 0 62 REXP 58.2u 
* Voltage on R62 used for G12, G14 in input stage
*
* Models
.MODEL NMI NMOS
.MODEL DESD  D   N=1 IS=1.00E-15 
.MODEL DL  D   N=1 IS=1F 
.MODEL DN1 D   IS=1P KF=146E-18 AF=1
.MODEL REXP RES TCE=10.1 
.ENDS MCP6001
```

Any suggestions as to what may be happening here? I should also note that the IRF530 MOSFET is just a placeholder while I select a proper one. Please do let me know if there's anything important that I left out. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Anywhere you see an E, replace it. Read the help. It says, "***It is better to use a G source shunted with a resistance to approximate an E source than to use an E source. A voltage controlled current source shunted with a resistance will compute faster and cause fewer convergence problems than a voltage controlled voltage source. Also, the resultant nonzero output impedance is more representative of a practical circuit.***" Sage advice. If you don't know how to do that, change your question (or write another, I suppose -- I don't really have a strong opinion about that.)

Comment: You've definitely made an oscillator. Does it work when you connect the op-amp in a more sensible circuit?

Comment: In particular, you are simulating for 1 second and the oscillation frequency is going to be very high.

Comment: This circuit won't work with IRF530 because it needs more Gate voltage than the MCP6001 can supply, and its Gate capacitance is much higher than the 100pF maximum recommended for stability.

Comment: Microchip's models are known to be problematic, it appears that this one is no exception. Try what @jonk said, but be careful to use the correct polarity for the output (you'll have to switch the order of the first two pins, i.e. `Gx Node2 Node1 ...` instead of `Ex Node1 Node2 ...`). Also try [reading this](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems%3F).

Comment: It looks like you are trying to build a constant current sink, so R1 and R2 seem out of place to me.  Are you sure you properly identified and connected your load?

Answer (score 1):

Your choice of transistor type is extremely unfortunate. I put an operational amplifier with a model I made myself. I also chose the right transistor. My models are available on my web page - http://bordodynov.ltwiki.org/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear that node 21 connects to any source:

```
I20 21 20 423U
D20 20  0 DN1
D21  0 21 DN1
```

These are the only components that are connected to those nodes, and this is probably confusing the solver try installing a small cap across them (like 1nF or 1pF something incosequintial) since they are constant and for some reason the solver can't figure it out (looks like a pretty deterministic circuit to me, but it might be the two diodes with the current source are hard to resolve).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1e9OOm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>